# how to show all beamer created slides for one page in one page

Tags: beamer, transition

I have a beamer document with the following code

```
\begin{frame}{a frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> item 1 txt
        \item<2-> item 2 txt
        \item<3-> item 3 txt
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

the generated pdf has 3 slides for this page and it's ok for the presentation. But what I want is to export another pdf that is good for furder reading by disabling the transition for each page so the above code would create only one slide. this way is better for reading the pdf but it's not good for presentaion.

I want a command that helps me create both pdfs for both usages without needing to remove all `<i->` from the document.

Comment: Look for `handout` option in the manual!, it's doing exactly that (and more).

Comment: BTW, next time please post a complete minimal document...

Comment: Thanks @Rmano it solves the problem and also based on your comment I find another question and made this one a duplicate.